# What is the difference between matTooltip and [matTooltip]?

Tags: angular, function, angular6

I would like to know the difference and

how the binding of values happen in the following cases . for example

1. [matTooltip]
2. matTooltip(without the bracket)
3. (click)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) With brackets - Takes a variable value; e.g

`const myTooltip: string = 'My tooltip text'`

`<button [matTooltip]="myTooltip">Click</button>`

Use when your tooltip text may vary based on conditions, so you control the text from your component logic.

---

2) Without brackets - Takes a string value directly; e.g

`<button matTooltip="My tooltip text">Click</button>`

Use when your tooltip will never change, so you keep the text directly in the template.

---

3) Event handler - takes a function; e.g

`<button (click)="myButtonClickHandler()">Click</button>`

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to check this link :
 https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

It contain all what you need to know about the **Template Syntax** and more,
This page is a comprehensive technical reference to the Angular template language. It explains basic principles of the template language and describes most of the syntax that you'll encounter elsewhere in the documentation.

I hope that will help you !

Answer (score 0):

One further point of clarification- ANY property in an html tag can be used with brackets, including native properties.  Any property without brackets will use the literal string value provided, so something like `<div id="test">` will use the literal value "test" for the id.  However, `<div [id]="test">` will look for a variable called "test" in the scope of your component and use that value, and error if the variable is undefined.  You can do this with any native property.